# Add rows to an empty tbody element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have table like this:

```
<table id="search-table" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Something</th>
      <th>Something2</th>
      <th>Something3</th>
      <th>Something4</th>
      <th>Something5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I have an API call which returns data that I want to put as row and columns in the empty tbody element.

```
var body = document.getElementsbyTagName("tbody");
var x = 0;

for (i = 0; i < APIcall.length; i++) {
  var createRow = body.insertRow();
  for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    var x = createRow.insertCell(j);
  }
}
```

If I insertRow on the thead element the rows are created, but not when I try to add it to tbody. Probably me just misunderstanding something. Any suggestions what I should do?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or not?

Comment: There's so many errors in your code that actually, nothing is happening.  Try to recreate the error and look in the console for errors.

Comment: Example: getElementsbyTagName - no such function (typo).  getElementsByTagName returns an array, so you need `getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]`.    Fix these and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/zaqg1pr0/

Comment: `getElementsbyTagName`  should be `getElementsByTagName`. Writing code is also about precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're almost there.

First, as Rory mentioned, you're not targeting the `tbody` in DOM.
You can fix that by replacing the first line with this:

```
var body = document.querySelector('#search-table tbody')
```

What that does, is this: It looks for an element with an ID of `search-table` and a descendant `<tbody>` and returns a reference.

Your code would run without an error then, but I'm confused about the result.
In the second line, you have `var x = 0` but later on I can see `var x = createRow.insertCell(j);` also. (The second `x` would give you a reference to a new `<td>` element).

Hope that helps.

Comment: `var x = 0` is likely just a misunderstanding of how variables work and they're initialising with *something* rather than leaving uninitialised.    Uninitialised will give an error if it's used before init while init on the var won't give that error, just give crazy hard to find logic errors if it's used before correct init.

Comment: I know that, but perhaps it is part of a bigger context.
Also, I'd go for `const` and `let`. But it could be an assignment or something.

Comment: I know *you* know that :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var html ='';
for (i = 0; i < APIcall.length; i++) {`enter code hereenter code here
  html += '<tr><td>' + APIcall[i].somthing + '</td><td>'+ APIcall[i].somthing + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + APIcall[i].somthing + '</td>' + < td > '+APIcall[i].somthing+' </td>'+
  '<td>' + APIcall[i].somthing + '</td></tr>';

}
$('#search-table > tbody').append(html);

enter code here
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have more than one tbody in your markup, you have to target your's specifically because getElementsByTagName returns an array of elements.

for eyample:

```
var tbodies = document.getElementsbyTagName("tbody");
var targetTbody = tbodies[0];
```

or you could loop over tbodies if you want to add your stuff to multiple tbodies.

Comment: However `getElementsbyTagName` does nothing but give you an error...